# How can I change the words on the heading of the odd pages without using the macro '\jname.'

Tags: header-footer

If I want to print something on the heading of **even pages**, I can use the macro '**\authormark**,' e.g., '**\authormark{We are Authors}**.' That is because there is a '**\markright**' command in the definition of the '**\authormark**.'

```
\documentclass[DTMColor]{New-New}

\begin{document}

\authormark{We are Authors}

\articletype{RESEARCH ARTICLE}

\jnlPage{1}{00}
\jyear{2021}
\jdoi{10.1017/xxxxx}

\title[AAA]{Hello, I am the template.}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

This is an introduction.

\subsection{Introduction to \LaTeX}

\newpage

\section{New Section}

This is a new section.

\newpage

\section{New Section2}

This is a new section2.

\end{document}
```

[image]

For the **odd pages**, I **do not** want to use the macro '**\jname**' because I think it means the journal's name. I will not change the journal's name. In the meantime, the guide of the journal **forbids** the command '**\markboth**.'

```
\jname{Where do these magic words come from?}
```

[image]
[image]

In the '**cls**' file, is there any **macro** that can be used to change the words on the heading of the odd pages?

There is the 'cls' file.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{New-New}

\newif\if@restonecol
\newif\if@titlepage   \@titlepagefalse
\newif\if@cropmarkson \@cropmarksonfalse
\newif\ifdtmcolor\global\dtmcolorfalse
\newif\ifonline\global\onlinefalse
\newif\ifbakoma\global\bakomafalse
\newif\ifnoquery\global\noqueryfalse
\newif\ifnolineno\global\nolinenofalse
\newif\iffinals\global\finalsfalse
\newif\if@issue\global\@issuefalse
\newif\ifOA\global\OAfalse

\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{dtmcol}{cmyk}{1,0.6667,0,0.4}

%% Template Options
\DeclareOption{OA}{\global\OAtrue}
\DeclareOption{a4paper}{\PassOptionsToPackage{a4}{crop}}
\DeclareOption{a3paper}{\PassOptionsToClass{a3paper}{article}\PassOptionsToPackage{a3}{crop}}
\DeclareOption{centre}{\PassOptionsToPackage{center}{crop}}
\DeclareOption{crop}{\PassOptionsToPackage{frame}{crop}\global\@cropmarksontrue}
\DeclareOption{nocrop}{\PassOptionsToPackage{off}{crop}\global\@cropmarksontrue}
\DeclareOption{info}{\PassOptionsToPackage{info}{crop}}
\DeclareOption{noinfo}{\PassOptionsToPackage{noinfo}{crop}}
\DeclareOption{bakoma}{\global\bakomatrue\global\onlinetrue}

%% Classfile Options
\DeclareOption{oneside}{\@twosidefalse \@mparswitchfalse}
\DeclareOption{twoside}{\@twosidetrue  \@mparswitchtrue}
\DeclareOption{draft}{\setlength\overfullrule{5pt}}
\DeclareOption{titlepage}{\@titlepagetrue}
\DeclareOption{notitlepage}{\@titlepagefalse}
\DeclareOption{onecolumn}{\@twocolumnfalse}
\DeclareOption{twocolumn}{\@twocolumntrue}
\DeclareOption{openbib}{\let\if@openbib\iftrue}
\DeclareOption{DTMColor}{\global\dtmcolortrue}
\DeclareOption{online}{\global\onlinetrue}
\DeclareOption{finals}{\global\finalstrue\global\noquerytrue}
\DeclareOption{noquery}{\global\noquerytrue}
\DeclareOption{issue}{\global\@issuetrue}

\ExecuteOptions{online,finals,twosidecrop,crop,centre,info,croppage}
\ProcessOptions
\LoadClass[twoside,fleqn]{article}

%% General Packages Used
\RequirePackage{url}
\RequirePackage{soul}
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Fonts & Sizes %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\rm}{\normalfont\rmfamily}{\mathrm}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sf}{\normalfont\sffamily}{\mathsf}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\tt}{\normalfont\ttfamily}{\mathtt}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\bf}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\mathbf}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\it}{\normalfont\itshape}{\mathit}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sl}{\normalfont\slshape}{\@nomath\sl}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sc}{\normalfont\scshape}{\@nomath\sc}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\cal{\@fontswitch\relax\mathcal}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\mit{\@fontswitch\relax\mathnormal}

\def\spreadout#1{%
     \gdef\temp{#1}%
  \dimen0 = \spreadoutfactor pt
  \ifdim\dimen0=\z@\temp\else                            % If the spreadoutfactor
  \expandafter\dospreadout\temp\endmark\kern-\dimen0\fi} % is zero, then we can use kern or hskip
%                                                        % with the title etc. Suppressed the extra space
%                                                        % after spreadout.
\def\dospreadout{%
  \afterassignment\findospreadout
  \let\next= }
%
\def\findospreadout{%
   \ifx\next\endmark
      \let\nextaction = \relax
   \else
      \let\nextaction = \dospreadout
      \next
      \kern\dimen0
   \fi
   \nextaction}
%%


\renewcommand\normalsize{%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize{10pt}{12pt}%
   \abovedisplayskip 9.5\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus0\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip 3\p@ \@plus3\p@%
   \belowdisplayshortskip 9.5\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus3\p@%
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip%
   \let\@listi\@listI}%
\normalsize
\newcommand\medsize{%
   \@setfontsize\small\@xipt{13}%
   \abovedisplayskip 5\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus4\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus2\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 3\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
   \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
               \topsep 4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
               \parsep 2\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus\p@
               \itemsep \parsep}%
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip}
\renewcommand\small{%
   \@setfontsize\small\@ixpt{11}%
   \abovedisplayskip 5\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus4\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus2\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 3\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
   \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
               \topsep 4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
               \parsep 2\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus\p@
               \itemsep \parsep}%
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip}
\renewcommand\footnotesize{%
   \@setfontsize\footnotesize{7}{8}%
   \abovedisplayskip 5\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus4\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 3\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus2\p@
   \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
               \topsep 3\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus\p@
               \parsep 2\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus\p@
               \itemsep \parsep}%
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip}
%
\renewcommand\scriptsize{\@setfontsize\scriptsize\@ixpt\@ixpt}
\newcommand\scrisize{\@setfontsize\scrisize{9.3}{9}}
\renewcommand\tiny{\@setfontsize\tiny\@vpt\@vipt}
\renewcommand\large{\@setfontsize\large{12}{14}}
\newcommand\larg{\@setfontsize\larg{11}{13}}
\renewcommand\Large{\@setfontsize\Large{16}{18}}
\renewcommand\LARGE{\@setfontsize\LARGE\@xviipt{22}}
\renewcommand\huge{\@setfontsize\huge\@xxpt{25}}
\renewcommand\Huge{\@setfontsize\Huge\@xxvpt{30}}
%
\DeclareMathSizes{\@ixpt}{\@ixpt}{7}{5}
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xpt}{\@xpt}{7}{5}
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xipt}{\@xipt}{7}{5}

\DeclareRobustCommand*\textsubscript[1]{%
  \@textsubscript{\selectfont#1}}%
\def\@textsubscript#1{%
  {\m@th\ensuremath{_{\mbox{\fontsize\sf@size\z@#1}}}}}

%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Layout Settings %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%

\RequirePackage{geometry}

%% Regular Pages (for Opening page - redefined)
\geometry{%
    paperwidth=174mm,
    paperheight=247mm,
    top={57pt},
    headheight={7pt},
    headsep={19.5pt},
    textwidth={144mm},
    textheight={595pt},
    marginparsep=3mm,
    marginparwidth=10mm,
    bindingoffset=6mm,
    footskip=0mm}
%

\setlength{\marginparsep}{3mm}%
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{10mm}%

\setlength\footskip{0\p@}
\setlength\maxdepth{0pt}

\setlength\footnotesep{5.75\p@}
\setlength{\skip\footins}{8\p@ \@plus 4\p@ \@minus 0\p@}

\setlength\parindent{12pt}
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Pagination Settings %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% Line spacing
\setlength\lineskip{1\p@}
\setlength\normallineskip{1\p@}
\renewcommand\baselinestretch{}
\parskip=0pt

% Page break penalties
\@lowpenalty   51
\@medpenalty  151
\@highpenalty 301

% Disallow widows and orphans
\clubpenalty 10000
\widowpenalty 10000

% Disable page breaks before equations, allow pagebreaks after
% equations and discourage widow lines before equations.
\displaywidowpenalty 100
\predisplaypenalty   10000
\postdisplaypenalty  0

% Set these global demerits
\doublehyphendemerits 1000000   % corresponds to badness 800
\finalhyphendemerits  1000000  % corresponds to badness 1000

% Allow loose lines rather than overfull lines
\vbadness=9999
\tolerance=9999

% Allow breaking the page in the middle of a paragraph
\interlinepenalty 0

% Disallow breaking the page after a hyphenated line
\brokenpenalty 10000

% Hyphenation; don't split words into less than three characters
\lefthyphenmin=3
\righthyphenmin=3

% Float placement parameters

% The total number of floats that can be allowed on a page.
\setcounter{totalnumber}{10}

% The maximum number of floats at the top and bottom of a page.
\setcounter{topnumber}{5}
\setcounter{bottomnumber}{5}

% The maximum part of the top or bottom of a text page that can be
% occupied by floats. This is set so that at least four lines of text
% fit on the page.
\renewcommand\topfraction{.921}
\renewcommand\bottomfraction{.921}

% The minimum amount of a text page that must be occupied by text.
% This should accomodate four lines of text.
\renewcommand\textfraction{.13}

% The minimum amount of a float page that must be occupied by floats.
\renewcommand\floatpagefraction{.887}

% The same parameters repeated for double column output
\renewcommand\dbltopfraction{.88}
\renewcommand\dblfloatpagefraction{.88}

% Space between floats
\setlength\floatsep    {18\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 2\p@}

% Space between floats and text
\setlength\textfloatsep{19\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 4\p@}

% Space above and below an inline figure
\setlength\intextsep   {18\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 2\p@}

% For double column floats
\setlength\dblfloatsep    {20\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 2\p@}
\setlength\dbltextfloatsep{18\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 4\p@}

\hyphenation{Figure Figures Table Tables Equation Equations Section Sections Appendix Theorem Lemma}

%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Math Settings %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% For above/below spacing
\def\eqnarray{%
   \stepcounter{equation}%
   \def\@currentlabel{\p@equation\theequation}%
   \global\@eqnswtrue
   \m@th
   \global\@eqcnt\z@
   \tabskip\@centering
   \let\\\@eqncr
   $$\everycr{}\halign to\displaywidth\bgroup
       \hskip\@centering$\displaystyle\tabskip\z@skip{##}$\@eqnsel
      &\global\@eqcnt\@ne\hskip \tw@\arraycolsep \hfil${##}$\hfil
      &\global\@eqcnt\tw@ \hskip \tw@\arraycolsep
         $\displaystyle{##}$\hfil\tabskip\@centering
      &\global\@eqcnt\thr@@ \hb@xt@\z@\bgroup\hss##\egroup
         \tabskip\z@skip
      \cr
}
\def\endeqnarray{%
      \@@eqncr
      \egroup
      \global\advance\c@equation\m@ne
   $$\@ignoretrue
}
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Titles %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%

\renewcommand\contentsname{Contents}
\renewcommand\listfigurename{List of Figures}
\renewcommand\listtablename{List of Tables}
\renewcommand\refname{References}
\renewcommand\indexname{Index}
\renewcommand\figurename{Figure}
\renewcommand\tablename{Table}
\renewcommand\partname{Part}
\renewcommand\appendixname{Appendix}
\renewcommand\abstractname{Abstract}
%\renewcommand\abstractname{Summary}

%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Article Front Matter %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%

%% Article Type
\sodef\letterspacetwty{}{.1em}{.4em plus1em}{.5em plus 1em minus1em }
\def\articletype#1{\gdef\ArtType{\letterspacetwty{#1}}\gdef\@ArtType{#1}}%
\articletype{RESEARCH ARTICLE}%

%% Meta Info
\def\@artid{xx}
\def\@jname{xxx xxx}
\def\@jvol{xx}
\def\@jissue{xx}
\def\@jyear{{0000}}
\def\@jmonth{xx}
\def\@DOI{}
\def\@logourl{}
%
\def\artid#1{\gdef\@artid{#1}}
\def\jname#1{\markboth{\textit{#1}}{\textit{#1}}\gdef\@jname{#1}}
\def\jvol#1{\gdef\@jvol{#1}}
\def\jissue#1{\gdef\@jissue{#1}}
\def\jyear#1{\gdef\@jyear{#1}}
\def\jmonth#1{\gdef\@jmonth{#1}}
\def\jdoi#1{\gdef\@DOI{#1}\gdef\@logourl{#1}}
\jdoi{10.4153/xxxx}
%\jname{Data/Math}%
\jname{Where do these magic words come from?}
%

%%% Font Def
\def\Titlefont{\fontfamily{\rmdefault}\fontsize{16}{18}\fontseries{b}\selectfont\raggedright}
\def\Artcatfont{\fontfamily{\rmdefault}\fontsize{8.5}{10.5}\fontseries{b}\selectfont}
\def\Authorfont{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}
\def\addressfont{\fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont\raggedright}
\def\abstractheadfont{\fontfamily{\rmdefault}\fontsize{9}{11}\fontseries{b}\selectfont}%
\def\abstractsubheadfont{\fontfamily{\rmdefault}\fontsize{9}{11}\fontseries{b}\selectfont}%
\def\abstractfont{\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont}%
\def\keywordfont{\fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont}%
\def\historyfont{\fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont\raggedright}

%% Article Title
%\def\title#1{\gdef\@title{#1}}

\renewcommand{\title}[2][]{%
\gdef\@checktitle{#1}\ifx\@checktitle\empty\gdef\@title{#2}
\gdef\s@title{#2}\else\gdef\@title{#2}\gdef\s@title{#1}\fi}

%% Cross Link for Author & Address
\def\jmkLabel#1{\@bsphack\protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\Newlabel{#1}{\@currentlabel}}\@esphack}
\def\Newlabel#1#2{\expandafter\xdef\csname X@#1\endcsname{#2}}
\def\jmkRef#1{\@ifundefined{X@#1}{0}{\csname X@#1\endcsname}}

%% Article Author(s)
\let\sep\@empty%
\let\authorsep\@empty%
\newcount\aucount%
\newcount\punctcount%
\def\author{\advance\aucount by 1\@ifstar\@@corrauthor\@@author}%
\def\au@and{\ifnum\punctcount=2\ and\else\unskip,\advance\punctcount by -1 \fi}%
\def\artauthors{}
\newif\if@auemail%
\newcommand{\@@author}[2][]{\g@addto@macro\artauthors{%
    \ifnum\aucount=1%
    \global\@auemailtrue%
    \else%
    \global\@auemailfalse%
    \fi%
    \Authorfont%
    \def\baselinestretch{1}%
    \authorsep{#2}\unskip\ifx#1\empty\else\textsuperscript{\smash{{%
      \@for\@@affmark:=#1\do{\edef\affnum{\@ifundefined{X@\@@affmark}{1}{\jmkRef{\@@affmark}}}%
     \unskip\sep\affnum\let\sep=,}}}}\fi%
    \def\authorsep{\au@and~}%%%
    \global\let\sep\@empty\global\let\@corref\@empty%
}}%

\newcommand{\@@corrauthor}[2][]{\g@addto@macro\artauthors{%
    \global\@auemailtrue%
    \Authorfont%
    \def\baselinestretch{1}%
    \authorsep{#2}\unskip\ifx#1\empty\else\textsuperscript{\smash{{%
      \@for\@@affmark:=#1\do{\edef\affnum{\@ifundefined{X@\@@affmark}{1}{\jmkRef{\@@affmark}}}%
     \unskip\sep\affnum\let\sep=,}}}}\fi%
    \def\authorsep{\au@and~}%%%
    \global\let\sep\@empty\global\let\@corref\@empty%
}}%
%
\RequirePackage{ltxcmds}%
\def\authororcid#1{%
\ltx@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{\href{https://orcid.org/#1}{\includegraphics{orcid_logo}}}{{\includegraphics{orcid_logo}}}%
}
\newcommand{\orcid}[1]{\protect\g@addto@macro\artauthors{%
\authororcid{#1}%
}}
%
%% Author Email
\newif\ifcorrauth
\def\addressrule{\kern-10\p@ \hrule \@height.15pt \@width\marginparwidth \kern 1.6\p@}%
\def\@email{}
\DeclareUrlCommand\myemail{}%
\def\email#1{
{\hbox{E-mail:}~}\ifonline\textcolor{blue}{\protect\myemail{#1}}\else{\protect\myemail{#1}}\fi}%
\let\nomail\relax


\def\linkref#1#2{\ifonline\textcolor{blue}{\hyperlink{#1}{#2}}\else#2\fi}
\def\linktarget#1#2{\ifonline\hypertarget{#1}{#2}\else#2\fi}

\ifonline
\def\ArtDir{fig/online/}%
\else
\def\ArtDir{fig/}%
\fi

\def\doilink#1{\ifonline\href{https://doi.org/#1}{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}\else#1\fi}
\def\arxlink#1{\ifonline\href{https://arxiv.org/abs/#1}{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}\else#1\fi}
\def\emaillink#1{\ifonline\href{mailto:#1}{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}\else#1\fi}
\def\httplink#1{\ifonline\href{#1}{\textcolor{blue}{\refuri #1}}\else{\refuri #1}\fi}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% For continued Table %%%%%%%%%
%
\newenvironment{tabnote}{\tabnotefont\par}
    {\par\global\manshowtfootskip=0pt}
%

%\ifpuretex
%\def\gt{>}
%\def\lt{<}
%\else
%\fi

\def\Bbb#1{\mathbb #1}
%
\def\eqalign#1{\null\,\vcenter{\openup\jot\m@th
  \ialign{\strut\hfil$\displaystyle{##}$&$\displaystyle{{}##}$\hfil
      \crcr#1\crcr\ifx\intconteq\YES\noalign{\kern6pt}\else\fi}}\,}%

%\@mathmargin\@centering

\def\eqalignno#1{\displ@y \tabskip\@mathmargin
  \halign to\displaywidth{%
    \hfil$\@lign\displaystyle{##}$\tabskip\z@skip
    &$\@lign\displaystyle{{}##}$\hfil\tabskip\@mathmargin
    &\llap{$\@lign##$}\tabskip\z@skip\crcr
    #1\crcr}}%

\def\leqalignno#1{\displ@y \tabskip\@mathmargin
  \halign to\displaywidth{%
    \hfil$\@lign\displaystyle{##}$\tabskip\z@skip
    &$\@lign\displaystyle{{}##}$\hfil\tabskip\@mathmargin
    &\kern-\displaywidth\rlap{$\@lign##$}\tabskip\displaywidth\crcr
    #1\crcr}}%


%\newcommand{\AUSP}[1]{\def\spreadoutfactor{1.3}\spreadout{#1}}
\newcommand{\AUSP}[1]{#1}

\def\sn#1{\AUSP{#1}}
\def\gn#1{\AUSP{#1}}
\def\snsp#1{\kern1.2pt#1\kern1.1pt}
\def\gnsp#1{\kern1.2pt#1\kern1.1pt}

\def\aff#1{\protect\textsuperscript{\rm #1}}

\definecolor{snamecol}{rgb}{1,.64,1}
\def\LDAUTH#1{\ifnoquery{#1}\else\fboxsep0pt\fboxrule0pt\fcolorbox{snamecol}{snamecol}{#1}\fi}%


%% Corrseponding Address
\def\@copycorthanks{}
\def\auaddress{}
\def\@auaddress{}
\newcounter{affn}
\renewcommand\theaffn{\arabic{affn}}
\def\address{\@ifstar\@@coraddress\@@address}
\newcount\addcount% To check the count of address
\newcommand{\@@coraddress}[2][]{%\advance\addcount by 1
\g@addto@macro\auaddress{%
     \stepcounter{affn}%
     \xdef\@currentlabel{\theaffn}%
     \jmkLabel{\theaffn}%
     {\textsuperscript{#1}#2.}\par}
}

%% Author Address
\def\addsep{\par\vskip0pt}
\newcount\addcount% To check the count of address
\newcommand{\@@address}[2][]{\advance\addcount by 1\g@addto@macro\auaddress{%
     \stepcounter{affn}%
     \xdef\@currentlabel{\theaffn}%
     \jmkLabel{\theaffn}%
     {\textsuperscript{#1}#2.}\par}%\theaffn
}


%% Address tagging
\newcommand{\orgdiv}[1]{#1}%
\newcommand{\orgname}[1]{#1}%
\newcommand{\orgaddress}[1]{#1}%
\newcommand{\street}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\postcode}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\city}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\state}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\country}[1]{#1}

%% Author name in Running Head
\def\@authormark{}%
\def\authormark#1{\markright{{{#1}}}\gdef\@authormark{\def\etal{{et al.}}#1}\gdef\@authormarkforcite{\def\etal{\textit{et al.}}#1}}%
\def\etal{\textit{et al.}}

%% Optional Text
\def\artnotefont{\reset@font\fontfamily{\rmdefault}\fontsize{8.6}{13}\selectfont\raggedright}
\def\artnote#1{\gdef\@Artnote{#1}}\artnote{}%

%% Article Abstract
\newcommand\abstracthead{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}{-22pt \@plus2ex \@minus0ex}{0.0001pt}{\abstractheadfont}}
\newcommand\subabstracthead{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}{3pt \@plus0ex \@minus0ex}{-.5em}{\abstractsubheadfont}}

\def\@abstract{}%
\long\def\abstract#1{\def\@abstract{%
\let\paragraph\subabstracthead%
\abstractfont%
\abstracthead*{\ifdtmcolor\textcolor{dtmcol}{\abstractname}\else\abstractname\fi}%
#1\par}}%

\def\printabstract{\ifx\@abstract\empty\else\@abstract\fi\par}%

\def\printkeywords{\ifx\@keywords\empty\else\@keywords\fi\par}%

%
%% Keywords
\def\keywordname{Keywords}
\newcommand{\keywords}[2][\keywordname]{%
\g@addto@macro\@keywords{\par\addvspace{5pt}{\keywordfont\textbf{#1:} #2\par}}}
\def\@keywords{}
\newcommand{\codes}[2][Primary]{\textit{#1} -- #2}%

%% Article History

\newcommand{\received}[2][Received:]{\g@addto@macro\@history{{\textbf{#1} #2}}}%
\newcommand{\revised}[2][Revised:]{\g@addto@macro\@history{{; \textbf{#1} #2}}}%
\newcommand{\accepted}[2][Accepted:]{\g@addto@macro\@history{{; \textbf{#1} #2}}}%

\def\CTAtitle#1{\gdef\@CTAtitle{#1}}\CTAtitle{}
\def\CTAauthors#1{\gdef\@CTAauthors{#1}}\CTAauthors{}
\def\jnlPage#1#2{\gdef\first@page{#1}\gdef\last@page{#2}}

\def\citeauth#1{\gdef\@citeauth{#1}}\citeauth{}
\def\endcteinfo#1{\gdef\@endcteinfo{\vfill\noindent\rotatebox{90}{\rule{0.5pt}{60pt}}\@@par%
\fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont\noindent{\bfseries Cite this article:} #1}
}\endcteinfo{}%

\def\endctxt#1{\@endcteinfo{\@CTAauthors, ``\@title,'' {\it \@jname} {\bfseries\@jvol}(\@jissue), {{\first@page{--}\last@page} (\@jyear).} \href{https://doi.org/\@DOI}{\textnormal{https://doi.org/\@DOI}}\@@par}}

% \AtEndDocument{
% \endctxt{{\thepage{--}\pageref*{LastPage}} (\@jyear).} %1682--1702 (2020).}
% }
% \AtEndDocument{
% \endctxt{{\first@page{--}\last@page} (\@jyear).} %1682--1702 (2020).} %\pageref*{LastPage}
% }

\AtEndDocument{
%\endctxt{}%{\first@page{--}\last@page} (\@jyear).} %1682--1702 (2020).} %\pageref*{LastPage}
}


%% Article Header Definition
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}
{\noindent{\vbox{%
    \hsize\textwidth\parindent0pt%
    \vskip7pt%
    %% Aritle Type
    {\hbox to \textwidth{{\Artcatfont\ifdtmcolor\textcolor{dtmcol}{\ArtType}\else\ArtType\fi\hfill}\par}}
    {\vskip5pt\hbox to \textwidth{\ltx@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{\href{https://crossmark.crossref.org/dialog?doi=\@logourl}}{}{\includegraphics{CrossRef-logo}}\par}}
    %% Aritle Title
    \ifx\@title\empty\else%
        \vskip15.5pt%
        {\Titlefont\ifdtmcolor\textcolor{dtmcol}{\@title}\else\@title\fi\ifonline\pdfbookmark{\@title}{HLtitle}\else\fi\par}
        %\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\@title}% for bookmarks
    \fi%
    %% Aritle Authors, Address and Correspondings
    \ifnum\aucount>0
        \global\punctcount\aucount%
        \vskip10pt%
        \artauthors\par%%     authors and emails
        {\vskip7pt\addressfont\auaddress\par%%      corresponding adress
        %\corremail\par
        }
     \fi%
     {\printhistory\par}%
     {\printkeywords\par}%
     {\printabstract\par}%
    }}\par\addvspace{23pt plus0pt minus0pt}}

%% Printing Article Header
\renewcommand\maketitle{\par
  \@afterindentfalse%
  \begingroup
    \gdef\UrlFont{\rmfamily}%
    \renewcommand\thefootnote{\@fnsymbol\c@footnote}%
    \def\@makefnmark{\rlap{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\smash{\@thefnmark}}}}%
    \long\def\@makefntext##1{\parindent 1em\noindent\small\selectfont
            \hbox{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}##1}%
    \if@twocolumn
      \ifnum \col@number=\@ne%
        \twocolumn[\@maketitle]%
      \else
        \twocolumn[\@maketitle]%
      \fi%
    \else%
      \newpage%
      \global\@topnum\z@% Prevents figures from going at top of page.
      \@maketitle%
    \fi%
    \thispagestyle{titlepage}%
  \endgroup%
  \global\advance\opshortpage23pt%
  \enlargethispage{-38pt}%
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
  \global\let\thanks\relax%
  \global\let\maketitle\relax%
  \global\let\@maketitle\relax%
  %\global\let\@thanks\@empty%
  \global\let\@author\@empty%
  \global\let\@date\@empty%
  %\global\let\@title\@empty%
  \global\let\title\relax%
  \global\let\author\relax%
  \global\let\date\relax%
  \global\let\and\relax
  %%%print continuous abstract on next page
  \@afterheading}%


\newenvironment{Frontmatter}{\par}{\maketitle\par}

\newenvironment{Backmatter}{\par\fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont
\def\sectionfont{\fontfamily{\rmdefault}\fontsize{10}{12}\fontseries{b}\selectfont\raggedright}
\def\paragraphfont{\fontfamily{\rmdefault}\fontsize{8}{10}\fontseries{b}\selectfont\raggedright\boldmath}
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-12pt \@plus -2ex \@minus 0ex}%
                                   {3pt}%
                                   {\sectionfont}}%
%\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
%                                    {2.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
%                                    {-.5em}%
%                                    {\paragraphfont}}
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                    {12.5pt \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                    {-4.0001pt}%
                                    {\paragraphfont}}
\def\bibfont{\fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont}%
}{\par}
\def\bysame{\leavevmode\hbox to3em{\hrulefill}}

%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Page Styles %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
\def\opheaderfont{\fontsize{7}{9}\selectfont}
\def\headerfont{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}
\def\footerfont{\fontsize{7}{8}\selectfont}


%% Regular Page Style
\def\ps@headings{%
    \def\@oddfoot{\hfill}
    \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot
      \def\@evenhead{{\headerfont \thepage\qquad\textit{\rightmark}\hfill}}%
      \def\@oddhead{{\headerfont \hfill\textit{\leftmark}\qquad\thepage}}%
      \let\@mkboth\markboth%
      }

\newdimen\opshortpage%

\def\printcopyright#1{#1}%%

\def\copytext#1{\def\@copyrighttext{\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}\footerfont #1\end{minipage}}}
\copytext{\textcopyright\ The Author(s) \@jyear.\ifOA This is an Open Access article, distributed under the terms of the Creative Commons Attribution licence (http://
creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/), which permits unrestricted re-use, distribution, and reproduction in any medium, provided the original work is
properly cited.\else\fi
}%

\def\doitext{doi:}

\AtEndDocument{\label{LastPage}}
\def\@opjournalheader{\textit{\@jname}\space\ {{(\@jyear),\ \textbf{\@jvol}:\@artid}} {\first@page{--}\last@page}\\ % \thepage{--}\pageref*{LastPage}
{\doitext\@DOI}}%

%% Opening Page Style
\def\ps@titlepage{%
     \def\@oddhead{{\hbox to \textwidth{%
      \vbox to 0pt{\vskip-5pt\rlap{\hbox to \textwidth{\hfill\includegraphics[scale=.75]{CUP_Logo}%\quad\includegraphics{DataMath_Logo}
      \hspace*{-1pt}}}}%
      \vbox to 0pt{\vskip-7pt\rlap{\parbox{\textwidth}{\opheaderfont\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}[b]{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}@{}l@{}}%
      \@opjournalheader%
      \end{tabular*}}}}%
      }}}%
     \let\@evenhead\@oddhead%
     \def\@oddfoot{\vbox to 0pt{\vskip-\opshortpage{\printcopyright{\@copyrighttext}}}}%%
     \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}%

%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Sections %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
```

Comment: It's not at all clear why you'd want to do this, because the copy editors will insert the journal name anyway.

Comment: And I suspect that is why they forbid using \markboth.